# How to save document in elasticsearch by springboot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have built the springboot project 2.6v with elasticsearch, I have an index named employee, this employee have 4 fields, firsname, lastname, section and salary, section is enum.
I am using RestHighLevelClient to interact with elasticsearch. when I use it to perform get operation it works fine, but when I use it as create doc, by the following code:

```
public Map<String,String> save(Employee employee) throws IOException {
    IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("employees");
    String jsonString = objectMapper().writeValueAsString(employee);
    request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);
    restHighLevelClient.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    return Map.of("ack","true");
}
```

it throws the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for Response{requestLine=POST /logs/_doc?timeout=1m HTTP/1.1, host=http://127.0.0.1:9200, response=HTTP/1.1 201 Created}
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1751) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1702) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1672) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:1029) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at io.arabot.elasticseach.service.LogService.save(LogService.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.arabot.elasticseach.controllers.LogController.createLog(LogController.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:209) ~[na:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteResponse.<init>(DocWriteResponse.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.<init>(IndexResponse.java:28) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse$Builder.build(IndexResponse.java:96) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse.fromXContent(IndexResponse.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2011) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAndParseEntity$8(RestHighLevelClient.java:1673) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1749) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.15.2.jar:7.15.2]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```